# How to update SSD Firmware on RAID Controllers

Tags: ssd, hardware-raid, firmware

Got some servers with RAID Controllers and SSD.

Raid Controller: LSI MegaRaid 9271-4i
SSD: Intel 520

The MegaRaid controllers have the ability to update drive firmware using MegaCLI.

Intel for example only offers a Firmware Update Tool, and not direct .bin Firmware files.

Is there a possibility to update these drives without pulling them out and attaching them to a normal SATA controller and using the FUT? 
Any other ways you can think of for doing this? Or do people using RAID Controllers + SSD not update their SSD Firmware's at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have an option to do this through your RAID controller. In practice, I don't update SSD firmware unless it's fully vendor-integrated (Like Fusion-io or HP-branded and Dell-branded Sandisk enterprise disks).

If you DO need to update the firmware, you will need to connect directly to a SATA port and use the manufacturer's utility.

Answer (score 2):

You can update the firmware of specific (supported) Intel SSDs connected to a LSI/Avago/Broadcom RAID controller via the the Intel SSD Data Center Tool.

I came across the following info:
The Intel SSD DCT does not support SSD Data Center SATA drives behind HBAs (*exception: LSI Mega RAID adapters*).

The command to enable the LSI adapter is

```
c:\isdct>isdct.exe set -system EnableLSIAdapter = true
Set EnableLSIAdapter successful.
```

Reference: While the below reference is for Dell servers, I have used the [same process](http://learning-in-it.blogspot.com/2015/10/upgrading-intel-ssd-firmware-on-dell.html) on non-Dell servers with an LSI based RAID card.

Comment: This also works with the linux version of ISDCT :)